# Convert a byte[] array into a string of characters INCLUDING escape characters in java

Tags: java, python, arrays, string, hash

I searched google about this information but the answers I found do not apply to my case.

I have an HEX string like the following:

```
hexString = '7d940ef9790c31334ac6f116814148b9abe73f32'
```

Python can convert this string to a binary value using the following function:

```
unhexlify('7d940ef9790c31334ac6f116814148b9abe73f32')
```

whose result is:

```
binString = '}\x94\x0e\xf9y\x0c13J\xc6\xf1\x16\x81AH\xb9\xab\xe7?2'
```

That is, a **string** containing the binary information of the original hex string.
I tried to use the .getBytes("encoding") method in java, but I am not able to reproduce this result, and unfortunately this result is **critical** for my application (I need **exactly** the same result).
I'm not an encodings pro, so it could easily be me overlooking something.

I need to convert to the same kind of string as "binString" a byte[] array resulting from e.g. a md5 digest, so any insight on how to convert a byte[] to such a string would be most appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell more about unhexlify?

Comment: Unfortunately, unhexlify is not a very well documented method. The official docs say:
Return the binary data represented by the hexadecimal string hexstr. This function is the inverse of b2a_hex(). hexstr must contain an even number of hexadecimal digits (which can be upper or lower case), otherwise a TypeError is raised.

Comment: Come again about what you expect the result to be in Java. What you cite from Python isn't valid Java. A Java string is a counted sequence of UTF-16 code units (char, not byte). Where is the string supposed to go? Just back to hex again?

Comment: The expected result is a string, containing "\x" followed by the the original byte describing the corresponding character in the string.

Comment: That sounds like: Insert \x before every other character, making a total of 40 characters. But I don't think that's what you mean. I don't know Python but it appears that `'}\x94\x0e\xf9y\x0c13J\xc6\xf1\x16\x81AH\xb9\xab\xe7?2'` is a literal "string" of 20 bytes, none of which have anything to do with the characters \ or x. In Java, this is somewhat equivalent `"\u007d\u0094…"` but is a literal string of 20 UTF-16 code points, interpreting your byte sequence as text encoded with the ISO 8859-1 character encoding. It's probably best to approach this from the direction of how the result is used.

Comment: Reading "the corresponding character in the string" again, we can approach it from the source direction, too. Simple question, if the bytes represent characters, which encoding is being used? There is no text but encoded text. If the bytes represent characters, which character is meant by the byte 94?

Answer (score 0):

**It's not a solution**, but it could be helpful:

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String hexString = "7d940ef9790c31334ac6f116814148b9abe73f32";
        byte[] out = toByteArray(hexString);
        String result = new String(out,Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        System.out.println(result);
    }
    public static byte[] toByteArray(String s) {
        return DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(s);
    }
}
```

The output in my machine is:

> }??y13J???AH????2

It can print all the ascii chracters, but there are problems with the escape characters like \x.

Comment: I just tried this solution: the problem is, that I have a string "}??y13J???AH????2" or whatever as output in a similar way to getBytes("UTF-8"), while I need a string with all that "\x" nonsense.

Comment: @bjorn \x doesn't make sense in UTF-16 (string encoding in Java), so you have to find a way to *hardcode*.

Comment: I'm trying to understand this encoding stuff. i Think that "}\x94\x0e" is actually "}" + "characterIndicatedByHexCode94" + "haracterIndicatedByHexCode0E" etc etc. Hardcoding is not an option, as I need this string to be generated iteratively.  I know tht Python2 uses ASCII as default encoding, so I should suppose that the "hexCode" the character refers to is in ASCII, right?

Comment: Actually, } is 7d (0x7d). The problem with using new String(byte[], "UTF-8") that its behaviour is unspecified  when the array contains invalid bytes. You should probably use CharsetDecoder because it will throw an exception when the array contains an unmappable character.

Comment: @dsp_user Do you believe I could use "new String(byte[], "ENCODING")" to gain the same result?

Comment: No, because it seems that you have some nonsense characters (well, non-characters). Of course, you could try with different encodings and see what you get. BTW, do you have any control over how you create that hex string?